# New Line on PHP CLI

Tags: php

I have a php CLI script and cannot get the output to break on new lines. I do

```
echo 'this is my text\r\n';
echo 'next line';
```

This gives

```
this is my text\r\nnext line
```

Any ideas about how to get the output on different lines?

Comment: Use double quotes: `echo "\n";`.

Answer (score 306, accepted):

Use double quotes `"`.

```
echo "next line\n";
```

Additional you can use the system-dependent constant `PHP_EOL`

```
echo "this is my text" . PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: The use of PHP_EOL should be the preferred method of adding new lines.

Comment: @AutomaticPixel For platform compatibility yes, for inter-platform compatibility you should use `\n` instead.

Comment: it was helpful and real quick solution :) tnx for sharing

Comment: @KingCrunch what you mean by "inter-platform compatibility"?

Comment: @foozy For example you generate a something on linux but want to read it on a Mac-system, or Win-system. If you don't know the target system, or it can change (--> somebody forwards a mail with a generated file as attachment), use `\n`

Answer (score 18):

Use double quotes instead. `"`.

Answer (score 16):

Escape sequences are only parsed when inside double quotes, not single quotes.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Answer (score 12):

Better **not** to concatenate anything in PHP, because it may lead to unexpected results, instead use a comma:

```
echo 'Text with new line' , PHP_EOL;
```

This will be faster too by the way: not concatenating and avoiding parsed double quotes.