# SQL hourly query to work in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a SQL query that I run from SQLYog / WorkBench which pulls hourly rework information from a database and outputs into a table.

The query I use below:

```
SELECT HOUR(requested)AS `Hour`
, `ManualAction_L`.`name` AS `Rework Type`
, requestedByUsername AS `User`, COUNT(`KitManualAction_T`.`id`) AS `Count`
FROM KitManualAction_T, ManualAction_L
WHERE `KitManualAction_T`.`manualActionID`= `ManualAction_L`.`id` AND requested BETWEEN '2013-07-24 05:00:00' AND '2013-07-24 14:00:00'  
GROUP BY `Hour`, requestedByUsername, manualActionID
ORDER BY `Hour` ASC;
```

The problem that I have now is I want to automate the process via php / cron. I cant seem to get the query working in php and output the information in a table showing the hour, type, user and count.

The current output I get from SQLYog / Workbench looks like this:

```
>Hour Type  User    Count
>5  Create  heidis  70
>5  Create  lilly   27
>5  Reprint Label   lilly   7
>5  Cease   lilly   6
>5  Create  meisies 78
>5  Reprint Label   meisies 5
>5  Create  ntsoanet    2
>6  Create  heidis  133
>6  Reprint Label   heidis  3
>6  Create  lilly   105
>6  Reprint Label   lilly   1
```

Here is the current php code I am playing around with

```
$con = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $dbname, $port, $socket)
or die ('Could not connect to the database server' . mysqli_connect_error());

$query = "SELECT HOUR(requested)AS 'Hour' , `ManualAction_L`.`name` AS 'ReworkType' , requestedByUsername AS 'User', COUNT(`KitManualAction_T`.`id`) AS 'Count' FROM KitManualAction_T, ManualAction_L WHERE `KitManualAction_T`.`manualActionID`= `ManualAction_L`.`id` AND requested BETWEEN '2013-07-24 05:00:00' AND '2013-07-24 14:00:00'   GROUP BY `Hour`, requestedByUsername, manualActionID ORDER BY `Hour` ASC";

if ($stmt = $con->prepare($query)) {
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($Hour, $ReworkType, $User, $Count);
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        printf("%s, %s, %s, %s\n", $Hour, $ReworkType, $User, $Count);
    }
    $stmt->close();
}
```

Comment: Running the query from PHP will return exactly the same results as running it from Workbench. What difference are you seeing?

Comment: You want to insert this data automatically into a table?

Comment: I am trying to get an output in php. However i am struggling getting the query working in php.

Comment: What are you trying to get it to look like?

Comment: You're not storing the value produced in the while loop in a variable and it looks like you have a space between  the variable $ReworkType

Comment: You can't assign a variable in an if statement `if ($stmt = $con->prepare($query)) {` , you don't even need an if there

Comment: @cujomalainey i am trying to get the data in a table, when i run the above php i get the data but it is plain text, no formatting

Comment: @Ian You can assign a variable in an if statement.

Comment: Part of the problem is you are not using the PHP EOL, refer to this please. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6818875/new-line-on-php-cli

Comment: @cujomalainey i get the same result with  printf("%s, %s, %s, %s" .PHP_EOL, than i do with the original code

Comment: Try a literal new line character

Comment: Are you printing this on a web page? Then you need to use `<br>` to get a newline.

Comment: He is using cron, so im under the impression he using cli

Comment: What do you mean by _it is plain text, no formatting_? What kind of formatting are you expecting? You're just printing the values separated by commas, that's what you'll get.

Comment: Currently i am testing the php code in a browser before sending the info out with phpmailer / cron

Comment: @Barmar that is my problem, i am struggling to get the data into a table

Comment: Ok, then after each line use <br/> there would be the confusion, or use proper HTML tables

Comment: You should create an HTML table, and send the email with `Content-type: text/html`.

Comment: @Barmar thanks for clearing that up. updated my code `printf("<tr><td>%s</td>, <td>%s</td>, <td>%s</td>, <td>%s</td></tr>", $Hour, $ReworkType, $User, $Count);` and now seems to be working

Comment: One last question, how would i go about getting the Hour value in a HH:MM format?

Comment: @Seb Honestly I never knew you could do that, not sure why you would want to do that, as surely it would always be true?

Comment: @Ian You can assign a variable in an if statement and check the content of the variable after the assignment. You can of course do that in two lines of code, but it also works in just one line. It's often used working through a database result pointer to fetch the rows until no more rows exist (using a while-loop).

Comment: @Seb thanks for the heads up, I knew about while statements however if I thought you had to have `!-` `>` `<` `>=` etc

Comment: @Stroes With the function [TIME_FORMAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time-format) you can format your hour value as you want.

Comment: @VMai thanks the TIME_FORMAT option gets me the right format but as soon as i use it, it no longer counts the rows. except it gives me a detailed report of everything for that time. instead of the totals for the hour